# What is the difference between UrlHelper.Route and UrlHelper.Link methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, urlhelper

Looking at the msdn ([UrlHelper.Route](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.urlhelper.route(v=vs.118).aspx), [UrlHelper.Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.urlhelper.link(v=vs.118).aspx))  they seem quite identical. Are there any reasons to use one or the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Route()` returns a relative URI, `Link()` an absolute one.

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/UrlHelper.cs). `Link()` prepends `Request.RequestUri` to the result of `Route()`.